# MS Graph: orderby=lastModifiedDateTime is failing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

According to the DOCs is the `lastModifiedDateTime` should be a valid parameter for the `orderby` :

**"Comma-separated list of properties that are used to sort the order of items in the response collection. Works for `name`, `size`, and `lastModifiedDateTime` fields."**

however, this request is failing:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?orderby=lastModifiedDateTime desc`

is this a bug? as it's working with the `name`

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to list the children item order by the ‘lastModifiedDatetime’.

Base on my test, It’s most likely a bug or by design. We can posted it on [Microsoft User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) to let developer know.